# Count a th cell's place in table row

Tags: jquery, html-table, css-selectors, jquery-countdown

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>ccc</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I find out that the th cell with "B" is the second in the th row?

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/SNj27/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**`eq()`**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) if it's always the second `th` element you want to target:

```
$('th:eq(1)').text(); // returns 'B'
```

**Edit:**

If it's not always the second element, you could use [**`index()`**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to determine whether it is in the second row or not.

```
if ($(this).text().trim() === "B") {
    console.log($(this).index()); 
    // Returns 1 and 2 respectively for your jsFiddle (0 index based) 
    // Meaning the first 'B' is in row 2, the second is in row 3.
}
```

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/SNj27/2/)

---

**Note:** You should use [**`$.trim`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) instead of `trim()`, as in IE8 and before, you will recieve a syntax error using `trim()`:

```
if ($.trim($(this).text()) === "B")
```

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/SNj27/7/)

Comment: It's not always the second. Sorry if this was not clear. http://jsfiddle.net/SNj27/1/

Comment: @Martin No worries! Check out the note I left in my update regarding trim()

Comment: Thanks for the trim hint. Using $.trim() now. console.log() was also new to me. Much better than alert etc :)